# The integrand has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate or Infinity

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm tasked with investigating the decay rate of clusters over a period of time, the decay rate is given by ;
[image: details of integral]

```
 Clear[x]
G[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[10^16*(((x-2.82)^17)/((x+.021)^20))*(\[ExponentialE]^(-10^16*(((x-2.82)^17)/((x+.021)^20))*t)),{x,0,\[Infinity]}]
```

However when I try to evaluate, I receive the error that the integrand has evaluated OverFlow, Indeterminate or Infinity within boundaries {0.333,0}.
Could anyone please suggest an answer to solve this issue? Sorry if this seems elementary, my coding skills are still basic

Comment: Compare the logarithm of your exponential factor with the logarithm of the maximum number: ``(-10^16*(((x - 2.82)^17)/((x + .021)^20))*t) /. t -> 1 /. x -> 1/2.`` and ``Log@$MaxNumber``. You're well outside the computable domain here. Maybe you can transform the integrand?

Comment: @Bill made the correction but error still persists

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you very much!, will try searching for suitable substitution

Comment: @MichaelE2 instead of integrating to infinity i'm trying to integrate to a lesser value. for example 20 , values for t will be really low >0.001.  somehow the code still runs the same error,the value of the expression is below the max number for these values ;                                                                                                                                                     (10^15*(((x - 2.82)^17)/((x + .021)^20))*-10^16*(((x - 
          2.82)^17)/((x + .021)^20))*t) /. t -> .001 /. x -> 0.